ABAP Remote Filesystem extension issue - issue SAP with NW 7.47 unable to save back to SAP
When I modify the existing ABAP program and activate in VS Code, it's giving below error:

Failed to save 'ZALE_CUSTOMER_HIERARCHIE_DEL.fugr.abap': Unable to Write file 'adt://de3/System Library/ZBOA/Source Library/Function Groups/ZBOA_ALE_GEN/Function Modules/ZALE_CUSTOMER_HIERARCHIE_DEL.fugr.abap' (Error: Resource Function Module ZALE_CUSTOMER_HIERARCHIE_DEL is not locked (invalid lock handle: 4DC1B3B4798CD291059F30EC2D55376E582E8120))

In our SAP system the class CL_ADT_WB_RES_APP doesn't have a method CONFIGURE_SESSION_STATE, so we installed the plugin using abapGit.
We understand that we are on a lower version than the desired version of 7.51 and hence we must import abapGit in our ECC dev system for which we followed the link https://github.com/marcellourbani/abapfs_extensions
(About: "extended ABAP backend for visual studio code. Allow updates on older systems").
We have created zabapgit_standalone.prog.abap in our Dev system and executed as per the instructions given at https://docs.abapgit.org/user-guide/getting-started/upgrade.html.
Even though we followed all the steps given, we are still getting the above-mentioned error while activating and not sure on how to proceed further. Could you please guide us?

Just open an issue at https://github.com/marcellourbani/abapfs_extensions/issues/new.
